# Line info display in vim

Tags: vim

When I use the command, `:set paste`, in vim editor, the line info(line number, character number), displayed by default on the bottom right corner stops being displayed. How can I bring back that info. I don't want to use `:set number`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to show the ruler when paste is set. `:help ruler` clearly says:

> This option is reset when 'paste' is set and restored when 'paste' is
>   reset.

Nevertheless there is a workaround by simulating the default statusline.

Add the following lines to your `vimrc`:

```
set laststatus=2                    " Always show status line
set statusline=%f\                  " Show filename
set statusline+=%h%w%m%r\           " Show flags
set statusline+=%=                  " Align right
set statusline+=%(%l,%c%V\ %=\ %P%) " Show ruler
```

(Depending on the current contents of your `vimrc` you may have to adjust it properly.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `:set paste` if the idea is to copy&paste keeping the identation, you could paste using `:[line]pu[t]`, from vim `:help :put`:

```
:[line]pu[t] [x]        Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default
                        current line).  This always works linewise, thus
                        this command can be used to put a yanked block as new
                        lines.
```

So for example if you want to paste something after line 3 you would do:

```
:3put+
```

Just be sure to be in `normal` mode

Comment: I'm getting "invalid register name" error. I think I'm using it wrongly. With :set paste, I went into esc mode, and then typed ":set paste" and then went into insert mode and then pasted anything, anywhere. I used the command given by you in a similar way and am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting in normal mode, I think, keeps your indentation with no need of setting paste. Like:

```
"+p
```

This will paste your clipboard content

Comment: I don't really understand what exactly do you mean by "+p? Is this a command?

Comment: Yes, in normal mode this means: Register plus equals to "+ and then
p equals to paste